# I need to create a trigger to automatically increment the no_of_books in member table and book table

Tags: plsql, triggers

Upon issue, the value of `no_of_books` must be decremented in book table and incremented in member table

```
create or replace trigger trans_s_t3
after insert on trans_s 
select member_s as m1, book_s as b1 
for each row 
begin 
  update book_s , member_s 
  set no_of_books=:old.no_of_books - :new.no_of_books;
  where book_S=:new.book_no;
end;
```

Comment: you can't have 2 tables in a single update. Update should have a single table. If you want to update 2 table you have to write 2 update statements

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
 create or replace trigger trans_s_t3
    after insert on trans_s 
    select member_s as m1, book_s as b1 
    for each row 
    begin 
      update book_s 
      set no_of_books=:old.no_of_books - :new.no_of_books;
      where book_S=:new.book_no;
 update  member_s 
      set no_of_books=:old.no_of_books - :new.no_of_books;
      where book_S=:new.book_no;
    end;
```

Comment: Narasimha, I don't understand why you included the clause "select member_s as m1, book_s as b1" when you never referenced them?  Am I missing something?

Comment: No i just directly edited the query from the his question.@  StewS2

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a problem with Narasimha's answer, since it doesn't include the column name in the WHERE clause (as the original didn't).  I guessed it was BOOK_NO below, since it was never explicitly mentioned as a field in the book_s or member_s tables.

I think it should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trans_s_t3
    AFTER INSERT ON trans_s
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE book_s
       SET no_of_books = :old.no_of_books - :new.no_of_books;
    WHERE book_s.BOOK_NO = :new.book_no;
    UPDATE member_s
       SET no_of_books = :old.no_of_books - :new.no_of_books;
    WHERE book_s.BOOK_NO = :new.book_no;
END;
```

*Please mark this answer as useful if you find this to be, I could use the points.*

Thanks,

Stew